# Python - Binary Search on Log File with "Suspicious" Time

Tags: python, search, logging

Is there a way to do efficient binary search for "suspicious time" in a log file using `Python`?

I have a log file whose entry looks like this:

```
02:38:18  0  RcvTxData - 11 : Telegram received and process completed - MCP35 Tx -24239
02:38:20  0  RcvNewTxNo - 3 : MCP36 Set receive trigger
02:38:21  0  RcvNewTxNo - 1 : 
02:38:21  0  RcvNewTxNo - 1 : MCP35 get new Tx 24241
02:38:23  0  RcvTxData - 11 : Telegram received and process completed - MCP36 Tx -13918
02:38:23  0  RcvNewTxNo - 3 : MCP36 Set receive trigger
02:38:24  0  RcvNewTxNo - 1 : 
02:38:24  0  RcvTxData - 11 : Telegram received and process completed - MCP35 Tx -24241
02:38:24  0  RcvNewTxNo - 3 : MCP35 Set receive trigger
02:38:27  0  RcvNewTxNo - 1 : 
02:38:27  0  RcvNewTxNo - 1 : MCP36 get new Tx 13920
09:44:54  0  RcvNewTxNo - 1 : 
09:44:54  0  RcvNewTxNo - 1 : MCP24 get new Tx 17702
09:44:54  0  RcvNewTxNo - 2 : MCP24 Read last Tx before new Tx 17702
09:44:56  0  RcvNewTxNo - 1 : 
09:45:00  0  RcvTxData - 7 :MCP24 Prepare normal TxData to DB
09:45:01  0  RcvTxData - 8 :MCP24 complete call GetTxData
09:45:02  0  RcvTxData - 11 : Telegram received and process completed - MCP10 Tx -9008
09:45:02  0  RcvNewTxNo - 3 : MCP10 Set receive trigger
09:45:04  0  RcvNewTxNo - 1 : 
09:45:04  0  RcvNewTxNo - 3 : MCP24 Set receive trigger
09:45:16  0  RcvNewTxNo - 1 : 
09:45:16  0  RcvNewTxNo - 1 : MCP19 get new Tx 9133
09:45:16  0  RcvNewTxNo - 2 : MCP19 Read last Tx before new Tx 9133
09:45:17  0  RcvTxData - 1 :MCP19 gwTx-9133 lastTx-9131 newTx-0
09:45:17  0  RcvTxData - 4 :MCP19 Adjusted newTxNo_Val-9132
09:45:17  0  RcvTxData - 4.1 :MCP19 FnCode PF
09:45:23  0  RcvTxData - 1 :MCP24 gwTx-17706 lastTx-17704 newTx-0
```

As you can see from the above example, the log is having non-decreasing time and there could be a sudden jump in the time:

```
02:38:27  0  RcvNewTxNo - 1 : MCP36 get new Tx 13920
09:44:54  0  RcvNewTxNo - 1 : #there is a big jump here
```

My goal is to detect this suspicious line, returning its line and index.

I have created a function to detect this "suspicious time". However, the size of a log file is about `22,000` to `44,000` lines each. Thus, my algorithm is quite slow since I go from line to line:

```
f = open(fp, "r")
notEmpty = True
oldTime = None
while(notEmpty): #this can be executed 22,000 - 44,000 times
    l = f.readline()
    notEmpty = l != ""
    if not notEmpty:
        break
    t = datetime.datetime.strptime(l[0:8], fmt)
    if oldTime is None:
        oldTime = t
    else:
        tdelta = t - oldTime
        if tdelta.seconds > 3600: #more than 1 hour is suspicious
            print("suspicious time: " + str(t) + "\told time: " + str(oldTime))
        oldTime = t
```

Is there any way to quicken the search by something like, say, binary search on the log file in Python?

*(Note: suggestion for any alternative searching other than binary search, as long as it is better than brute force search is also equally appreciated)*

**Edit:**

I have partially implement [Torxed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/929999/torxed)'s solution (and fixing some of the errors):

```
with open(fp, 'rb') as fh:
    prev_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(fh.readline()[0:5].decode('utf-8'), '%H:%M')
    index = 0
    for line in fh:
        if len(line) == 0: continue
        index += 1
        t = datetime.datetime.strptime(line[0:4].decode('utf-8'), '%H:%M')
        if (t - prev_time).total_seconds() > 3600:
            print('\tSuspicious time:', t, '\told time:', prev_time, '\tat: ', str(index))
        prev_time = t
```

However, as he suggested some "hacks" in the answer, I would also like to add some additional characteristics of the file which might worth be "hacked" for addition performance benefits:

1. The entire file's timestamp, if not having suspicious time, is not lasted more than 6 hours from the first entry to the last entry
2. Between the two timestamp, if not having suspicious time, does not differ for more than 1 hour
3. The suspicious time will most likely occur after 20,000-th line and before 30,000-th line (thus, very possible some other lines can be skipped).

Is there any way to implement further "hack" here?

Comment: Do I understand this correctly? Your notion of suspiciousness depends on the difference of times between two lines? Will you know in which direction to search if a pair of lines is not a match?

Comment: It sounds like you're in need of a ordered index. Perhaps a database would be of use here?
If not this is a case of reading line-by-line since it's a raw format you're working with.

Comment: @L3viathan yes, you get it right. The index will be the one that has the larger value of the two time. In the example above, that would be the one with hour = 9.

Comment: @Torxed ideally yes... That would be better solution for long run. However, as I am given thousands of files now in the .txt files which are used elsewhere, I do not have the ideal situation mentioned..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This all boils down to re-factoring your code to make it as efficient (from a hardware + cache perspective).
I would consider some design changes and optimize the code to not create or call anything unnecessary while doing the read operations.

```
prev_time = None
with open(fp, 'rb') as fh:
    prev_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(fh.readline()[0:5].decode('utf-8'), '%H:%M')

    for line in fh:
        if len(line) == 0: continue

        t = datetime.datetime.strptime(line[0:5].decode('utf-8'), '%H:%M')
        if (t - prev_time).total_seconds() > 3600:
            print('Suspicious time:', t, '\told time:', prev_time)
        prev_time = t
```

First of all, instead of trying to do the logic **is old_time None?**, we simply fetch the first line and put a time in it before we enter our big `for ...` loop. This way we save a few microseconds for each line read, and that bundles up to a lot in the end.

Then we also use `with open` just because we don't want to leave any file handles open at the end. If you're going through a LOT of files, this is important.

We also skip the `is not notEmpty` 3 line logic with `is this line empty, if so continue`.

We also shorten down the time conversion to **not include seconds**, it's a minor edit but probably saves a lot of time in the end since we're only using 2/3's as much data in total for your operations.

One last improvement is that we open the **file as a binary object**, meaning we skip any automated `binary -> hex/ascii` conversion that might (is) done in the Python code. This will have a huge impact on handling speeds, the only down side to this is that `strptime` will require a string like object. My calculations tho (I have no huge source of text files atm) is that the conversion of 5 letters will be quicker than the overall speed of the python internals of converting a documents data from binary to string data. **I could be wrong here tho.**

Hope this improves your times a little bit.
**Oh and remember** that this only goes one way, meaning you'll get a negative value if the time difference goes backwards (which it probably won't in a sequential time log format.. but you never know)

Edit:

## seek hack

If you can some what predict a rough estimate of each lines length, it would actually be quicker to do:

```
data = fh.read(5)
t = datetime.datetime ...
fh.seek(128) # Skip 128 bytes, hopefully this is enough to find a new line.:
data = fh.read(5) # again
                              # This just shows you the idea, obviously not perfect working code here hehe.
```

to grab the `00:00` timestamp, obviously there would need to be a bit more to this logic, for instance, you need to monitor if you actually passed the line markings `\r\n` etc, but seeing as Python has no idea how long a row is but to seek for the `\r\n` markings vs you roughly knowing and being able to skip most of the data is a huge advantage in time seeking. So consider playing around this this as skipping the majority of the data vs using a generalized function of operation will always be quicker.

Note that we're in the pursuit of microseconds here, so every nutty idea and manual labor might actually pay off here.

**Additiona hacks using seek**:

Assuming you know that there will be **enough similar timestamps in a large pile** you could easily skip a few rows by doing:

```
for line in fh:
    if len(line) == 0: continue
    # Check the line

    fh.seek(56 * 10000) # Average length of a line is 56 characters (calculated this over a few of your lines, so give or take +-10 here)
                                     # And we multiply this with 10000, essentially skipping ~10k lines
```

If there's a **BIG** jump in time here, you could do:

```
    if diff > 3600:
        fh.seek(fh.tell() - 5000)
```

And jump back 5000 lines and check if the time difference still is as big as it was on 10k lines, then maybe you do have a time-difference. You could also use this to narrow down where the time difference happens (but I'll leave this up to you, there's niftier ways to find it with minimal manual labor that doesn't take up processing power).

Essentially this would could boil down to ~4 seeks in the best of worlds and manually doing `for line in fh` by checking for new line endings etc.. Something like this:

```
from functools import partial
import datetime
jump_gap = 56 * 10000 # average row length * how many rows you want to jump

def f_jump(fh, jump_size):
    fh.seek(fh.tell() + jump_size)
    while fh.read(1) not in ('\n', ''):
        continue
    return True

with open('log.txt', 'rb') as fh:
    prev_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(fh.read(5).decode('utf-8'), '%H:%M')
    f_jump(fh, jump_gap) # Jump to the next jump since we got a starting time

    for chunk in iter(partial(fh.read, 5), ''): # <-- Note here! We only read 5 bytes
                                                                 # there for it's very important we check for new
                                                                 # rows manually and set the pointed at the start
                                                                 # of a new line, this is what `f_jump()` does later.
        if chunk == '':
            break # we clearly hit rock bottom

        t = datetime.datetime.strptime(chunk.decode('utf-8'), '%H:%M')
        if (t - prev_time).total_seconds() > 3600:
            print('\tSuspicious time:', t, '\ttold time:', prev_time, '\tat: ', fh.tell())

        prev_time = t
        f_jump(fh, jump_gap)
```

**Disclaimer:** One limitation, I never count rows. But I do present you with the position where this occurred in the log file.

This is useful because you can do:

```
('\tSuspicious time:', datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 9, 44), '\ttold time:', datetime.datetime(1900, 1, 1, 2, 38), '\tat: ', 636)
```

You take `636` which is the file position,
you input that to `tail` like so:

```
[user@firefox ~]$ tail -c 636 log.txt 
ete call GetTxData
09:45:02  0  RcvTxData - 11 : Telegram received and process completed - MCP10 Tx -9008
09:45:02  0  RcvNewTxNo - 3 : MCP10 Set receive trigger
```

This shows me the *ish* line where the problem occurred and I can now backtrace the stuff.
Or I can go bananas and throw some Linux ninja magic around and do:

```
 x=`tail -c 636 log.txt -n 1`; grep -B 20 -A 3 "$x" log.txt
```

Which gives me the exact data where the stuff happened but also the 20 lines before so I can backtrace it a little bit.

And since you wanted line numbers (maybe for your boss or colleague), you can add `-n` to the grep command and get it that way:

```
x=`tail -c 636 log.txt -n 1`; grep -B 20 -A 3 -n "$x" log.txt

[user@firefox ~]$ x=`tail -c 636 log.txt -n 1`; grep -B 20 -A 3 -n "$x" log.txt
8-02:38:24  0  RcvTxData - 11 : Telegram received and process completed - MCP35 Tx -24241
9-02:38:24  0  RcvNewTxNo - 3 : MCP35 Set receive trigger
10-02:38:27  0  RcvNewTxNo - 1 : 
11-02:38:27  0  RcvNewTxNo - 1 : MCP36 get new Tx 13920
12-09:44:54  0  RcvNewTxNo - 1 : 
13-09:44:54  0  RcvNewTxNo - 1 : MCP24 get new Tx 17702
14-09:44:54  0  RcvNewTxNo - 2 : MCP24 Read last Tx before new Tx 17702
15-09:44:56  0  RcvNewTxNo - 1 : 
16-09:45:00  0  RcvTxData - 7 :MCP24 Prepare normal TxData to DB
17-09:45:01  0  RcvTxData - 8 :MCP24 complete call GetTxData
18-09:45:02  0  RcvTxData - 11 : Telegram received and process completed - MCP10 Tx -9008
19-09:45:02  0  RcvNewTxNo - 3 : MCP10 Set receive trigger
20-09:45:04  0  RcvNewTxNo - 1 : 
21-09:45:04  0  RcvNewTxNo - 3 : MCP24 Set receive trigger
22-09:45:16  0  RcvNewTxNo - 1 : 
23-09:45:16  0  RcvNewTxNo - 1 : MCP19 get new Tx 9133
24-09:45:16  0  RcvNewTxNo - 2 : MCP19 Read last Tx before new Tx 9133
25-09:45:17  0  RcvTxData - 1 :MCP19 gwTx-9133 lastTx-9131 newTx-0
26-09:45:17  0  RcvTxData - 4 :MCP19 Adjusted newTxNo_Val-9132
27-09:45:17  0  RcvTxData - 4.1 :MCP19 FnCode PF
28:09:45:23  0  RcvTxData - 1 :MCP24 gwTx-17706 lastTx-17704 newTx-0
```

Due to the nature of the `seek()` hack, fine-graining this might be a bit hard, but on this example I got the hit at `row 28` which isn't the actual row with the problem, but it gave me a close show, and with `tail + grep` i could backtrace it rather quickly to `row 12` being the faulty time-difference.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I appreciate it. I am not with my laptop now that I can't test your solution yet, but it looks more efficient than mine. You got my upvote. Will check again once my laptop is with me.

Comment: @Ian Thank you for the up vote and I hope this helps. If not I'd be happy to go back to the drawing board and help you identify your bottle necks. Remember that HW is a key factor in this equation. I've done numerous similar projects and HW speed is mostly what this comes down to. Multi-threading and stuff won't do much here for instance if the HDD's I/O is the bottleneck. Keep this in mind : )

Comment: I use your idea but modify the code which seems to contain run-time errors: `fh.readline()[0:4]` to `fh.readline()[0:5]` and `(prev_time - t).seconds` to `(t - prev_time).total_seconds()`. It works fine, thanks. :) but I am wondering about your "hack" - if there be any further way to "hack" the lines checking, if we are given more info. If you are free, please check my updated question.

Comment: @Ian Thanks for pointing out the syntax errors, wrote the majority of this on my mobile phone. Regarding the `seek()` "hack", I'll update my answer to match your edit/additional question.

Comment: @Ian Also added some additional code and linux voodoo you can perform. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks! This is more than sufficient, I think... I will check tomorrow in my office. It is already 11 PM in my timezone now. I really appreciate your help, thanks! :)

Comment: @Ian It was extremely quick, tried it on a few log files here. The problem is the fine-granularity when skipping lines this way. But with more logic this could narrow down to a specific row as well. Pleasure was all mine, good luck with your endeavors and perhaps we'll meet again over a question or two : )

Comment: OK, I modify a little bit here and there but the basic idea is really there. Thanks again! And we'll see each other around in the questions. :)

Comment: I started the bounty to further appreciate your effort. Let me know when do you want me to award it. :)

Comment: @Ian oh wow thanks, today is a great day I think hehe. Do you need any further assistance or just being a nice fellow programmer? :)

Comment: great! In that case, you need to wait for a couple more hours, for bounty can only be rewarded after a day, I suppose. :) No, your assistance is good enough. I just think that you got little noticed though your answer has helped me, so I put up the bounty simply to boost that up... ;)

Comment: @Ian I'd just like to extend my sincerest thank you. You're the first and only to give me more than what's necessary. I truly hope your project works out and I wish you the best of luck in the future. Again, my deepest and warmest thanks, keep being awesome!